# Batch File: Remove File Name Prefixes Based on Number of Characters Input

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to make a batch file that will remove specific prefixes from files within a folder.

eg. Rename "1 File1.txt" and "1 File2.txt" to File1.txt & File2.txt respectively.
The problem is that that the length of the prefix can vary. Here is the code I have:

```
@echo off
Set /p Prefix = Enter the prefix to eliminate:
rename "%Prefix%*.txt" "//*.txt"
```

Is there a way to make the amount of slashes (characters to remove) equivalent to the amount of characters entered by the user? Or another way to achieve the same thing?

Edit: Accidentally listed the files as "1 File1.txt and 2 File2.txt" - this was meant to be "1 File1.txt and 1 File2.txt" - all files with the same prefix (in this case, the prefix simply being "1 "

Comment: is there a common delimeter in your filename? like a space? like your example `1 file1.txt`

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `ren /?` or `rename /?` to get output the help of this command. The first argument string can be with path, but the second argument string being the new name must be without path. `/` is the directory separator on Unix/Linux/Mac while on Windows the forward slash is usually used for options. For compatibility reasons Windows kernel replaces all `/` by the Windows directory separator ``\`` in a file/folder string before accessing the file system. So it is not possible to use `/` in name of a file or folder.

Comment: See also the Microsoft article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). It looks like what you want is removing everything left to first sequence of one or more spaces in the file names. This can be achieved with `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir "* *.txt" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%C"`.

Comment: I recommend reading [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) You do not define an environment variable with name `Prefix`. You define an environment variable with name `Prefix ` with a space appended to name. Never use spaces left to equal sign on argument string of command `set`. And right to equal sign a space character is often also wrong, but in some cases intentionally used.

Comment: This question sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, space is a common delimiter

Comment: So, did you look at the answer I provided?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The solution you provided didn't seem to work, however the one from Mofi did
I appreciate the input and help from both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by Mofi in the comments is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!
The common delimeter is a space, so the code works great.

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir "* *.txt" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%C"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the prefix automatically, using your example files `1 file1.txt` `2 file2txt`:

```
@echo off
set /p "input=Enter Prefix to search: "
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d %input%*.txt') do (
   for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (%%a) do if not "%%i"=="" if not "%%j"=="" echo move "%%a" "%%j"
)
```

It will prompt the user for a prefix to search, i.e `1` and then do a search for anything containing `1*.txt` and rename it without the first delimeter.
So even if the user adds `255` as prefix, it will search for anything `255*.txt` (Note there are no spaces before or after my `=` in my set command.

This example will simply echo the move command and not actually move the files, if you want to perform the actual task, remove the `echo` command from the last for loop.

Keep in mind, if a file is called `1 and file1.txt` it will rename the file to `and file1.txt` because of `tokens=1,*` Also, we are only running this for files containing whitespace as per your examples, not `_` `-` etc, but can be changed if need be.

Lastly, you can also automatically rename all files, without having a user prompted. i.e

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
   for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in (%%a) do if not "%%i"=="" if not "%%j"=="" echo move "%%a" "%%j"
)
```